# How to manually lock mongodb database for read?

Tags: mongodb, collections

I want to switch collections *safely*, for example rename collection `foobar` to `foobar.old` and then some other collection back to `foobar`. As I understand between those renames there is a gap when any tries to read from `foobar` collection is going to end up with an error. Is there any way of swapping those collections more safely?

UPDATE:

I use `renameCollection`. As said, the problem is how to prevent clients from reading db for that brief moment of two renames.

Comment: What function(s) are you using to rename the collections?

Comment: `renameCollection` takes an exclusive global write lock and blocks all other operations until complete according to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/). But, is there a way you could use configuration rather than a fixed name to perform the same type of functionality without a global lock?

Comment: Please see updated question for the answers.